# Magento products collection change reload category page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-collection, category-listing

I am tring to change product collection using `catalog_product_collection_load_before`.
I need to sort products by `in stock`. Out of stock must be last.

following `config.xml`,

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        <observers>
            <gst_sales_order_observer>
                <class>Magecomp_Sortby_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>modifyProductCollection</method>
            </gst_sales_order_observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
</events>
```

following `Observer.php`

```
public function modifyProductCollection($observer)
{
    if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
    {   
        $products = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');

        //Inventory Stock 
        $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar');
        if ($toolbar) {
            $products = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

            $stockId = Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID;
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($products->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

            $products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inv' => $products->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
                "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId and _inv.stock_id=$stockId",
                array('stock_status')
            );
            $products->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());

            $products->getSelect()->reset('order');
            $products->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');

            if ($toolbar->getCurrentOrder()) {
                $products->addAttributeToSort($toolbar->getCurrentOrder(), $toolbar->getCurrentDirection());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Issue** When I reload category page product collection is change. any things wrong ?

Comment: Try getting the query and then understand what could be wrong with the sorting. Is there any other sorting logic added or this is the only one

Answer (score 0):

your event in config.xml should be like this:

```
...
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <Gst_Sales_Order_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>modelNameHere/observer</class> //exemple: sales/observer
                    <method>modifyProductCollection</method>
                </Gst_Sales_Order_Observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, but not working